# Looping as an expression

Tags: c#, .net, loops

I come across things where this would be useful rather often, and if it exists I want to know about it. I'm not really sure how to explain it to search for it, but it's basically a one line loop statement- similar to a lambada. This isn't the best example (it's a simple solution without this), but it's what was on my mind when I decided to finally ask this question. But this is the kind of thing I'm talking about.

(The following is what I'm thinking of looks like. I'm asking if something similar exists)

In my current situation, I am converting a string into a byte array to write to a stream. I want to be able to do this to create the byte array:

```
    byte[] data = String ==> (int i; Convert.ToByte(String[i]))
```

Where i is the number in the string based on it's length, and the next line is the output for item.

Comment: I am not sure what the client will do with the byte array, but please notice that `Convert.Byte()` will throw an exception for any character whose numerical value is larger than 255. Thus, it is better to use something like `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string)` to obtain the byte array -  the client could then use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[])` to turn the byte array back into a string.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, although Marcin gave me the answer I was looking for. Although for what I'm doing, I don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You should read about LINQ.
2. Your code can be written as:

   ```
   var String = "some string";
   byte[] data = String.Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x)).ToArray();
   ```

   or even with method group:

   ```
   byte[] data = String.Select(Convert.ToByte).ToArray();
   ```

Comment: Yes, I will look into that. This was just what I was looking for. It can't be used as much, but it's the exact functionality I wanted.